# oracle sub-query nesting issue

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to practice sub-querying in Oracel-sql and I am having a hard time understanding the concept of it.

In my code below I am trying to nest a table called item_loc into another table called store_item, the below code does not compile. I get an error of

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended 00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
```

I am not sure what to do to fix it?

```
 SELECT sub.store
 FROM store_item sub
   (SELECT item_id
    FROM item_loc
    WHERE item_id = 1134373
    )sub
  WHERE sub.store = 1
  ;
```

However when I run the code above but modify it, it runs. But I feel as if I ran the below code I would not need to nest anything. I am just trying to learn how nesting works.

```
  SELECT sub.*
  FROM 
   (SELECT item_id
    FROM item_loc
    WHERE item_id = 1134373
   )sub
   ;
```

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.) BTW, perhaps you want a `JOIN`?

Comment: are you calling these from JDBC?

Comment: No I am calling this from OCDB

Comment: try removing the semicolon

Answer (score 1):

problem is : you used alias `sub` twice. Maybe like this :

```
SELECT sub.store
 FROM store_item sub2
 WHERE item_id in
   (SELECT item_id
    FROM item_loc
    WHERE item_id = 1134373
    )
  AND sub2.store = 1;
```

OR

```
 SELECT sub.store
 FROM store_item sub2 join
   (SELECT item_id
    FROM item_loc
    WHERE item_id = 1134373
    ) sub ON sub.item_id = sub2.item_id -- i assume join condition
  WHERE sub2.store = 1;
```

i.e. you should compare two sets in two such different ways.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement contains at least two errors. First of all, it's FROM clause contains two different references with the same name 'sub'. Next, it should be either comma or join clause between them. To be correct, it should something like

```
 SELECT sub1.store
 FROM store_item sub1 join
   (SELECT item_id
    FROM item_loc
    WHERE item_id = 1134373
    ) sub2 on <<<some condition>>>
  WHERE sub1.store = 1
  ;
```

Moreover, it's not clear what you want to do. Do you wish to use nested tables? Or query with subqueries? Or something else?

Irrespective of other, it's hard to learn something on very artificial example. Try to find real problem in which you can use this technique, it's much easier.

Answer (score 0):

A subquery is similar to a table.

A table is a set of rows. A view is a set of rows. A result of select statement is a set of rows. All of them have the same "rights and responsibilities". Any set of rows could be used as a source of data in a `select` statement.

You can write:

```
select <columns list> from mytable
```

`mytable` here is a table. Next, you can treat this statement as a table and write the following:

```
select <something else>
  -- you replace here a name of a table with the query (which is a subquery)
  from (select <columns list> from mytable)
```

You can give an alias to a table/view/subquery:

```
select <columns list> from mytable t;

select <something else>
  from (select <columns list> from mytable) subquery
```

Here `t` and `subquery` are aliases.

Next, join. You can join any of this (table/view/subquery) with any:

```
select ...
  from mytable t,
       (...) subquery
 where t.column1 = subquery.column2
```

or

```
select ...
  from mytable t join (...) subquery
       on t.column1 = subquery.column2
```

Now, I think, it is obvious, what is wrong with your query.